# Adding UnsignedInteger in java and keep on getting Method call Expected

Tags: java

I keep getting method call expected errors. I am not sure what can I do. Does anyone have any idea on how can we make the main run without changing it?

Been trying for hours different methods and couldn't figure it out.

```
public class UnsignedInteger {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    UnsignedInteger three = new UnsignedInteger(3); // 3 is "autoboxed"
    UnsignedInteger four = new UnsignedInteger(4); // 4 is "autoboxed"
    UnsignedInteger sum = three.add(four);
    System.out.println(sum); // Should print 7
    try
    {
        UnsignedInteger broken = new UnsignedInteger(-1);
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Negative values are not allowed"); 
    }
int val;
// This is the constructor. It should throw an IllegalArgumentException if a 
//negative value is passed in
public UnsignedInteger(Integer value){
   if(value<0){
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("You have entered a negative number.");
    val=value;

   }
}

// This method will return the Integer that was passed in via the constructor.
public Integer getRawInteger()
{
    return val;
}

// Return the sum of the value stored in this object with the object passed as a parameter (i.e., otherUint)
// This should not mutate the state of our class.

public UnsignedInteger add(UnsignedInteger otherUint)
{
   return  getRawInteger(this.add(getRawInteger()));    }
}
```

Comment: Constructors do not return a value `return UnsignedInteger(getRawInteger());`

Comment: Some code seems to be missing from your question, eg. where is `class UnsignedInteger { ...`

Comment: stackoverflow didn't let me post the whole code "because it is too long" so I cut the class UnsignedInteger etc..

Comment: Please see [mcve]. We dont want your "full" code, but enough code to understand/repro the issue.

Comment: @GhostCat I knew my code was overwhelming but didn't know what to do about it. Thats understandable, thank you. I will use that method next time.

Comment: And just for the record: instead of putting test code into main functions: learn how to write JUnit test cases. That is how you test stuff in 2018. Using main() is like 2000.

Comment: @GhostCat I will look that up, I just start coding. Still very fresh to it. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: And please note: this is not a tutor service. You asked a question, and got an answer. Dont go and ping/pong more questions in comments....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public UnsignedInteger(Integer value)` is a constructor, but you are trying to call it as a method here:

```
return UnsignedInteger(getRawInteger());
```

and here:

```
return UnsignedInteger();
```

To call a constructor, you should write:

```
return new UnsignedInteger();
```

Besides, the `public UnsignedInteger(Integer value)` constructor shouldn't have a return statement, since constructor don't return a value.

In addition, `getRawInteger` is supposed to return an `Integer`, but you are returning a `UnsignedInteger`.

Comment: I still get an error using return new UnsignedInteger();

Comment: @HussamJumah well, `getRawInteger` should return an `Integer`.

Comment: how to pass a value to getRawInteger from the constructor?

Comment: @HussamJumah you should store it in an instance variable.

Comment: Can you please explain to me why gives me unhandled exception error? In other words.. How can I handle it?
   ` throw new IllegalAccessException("You have entered a negative number.");`

Comment: @HussamJumah `IllegalAccessException` is a checked exception, so you have to add a `throws IllegalAccessException` clause to the method or constructor that throws that exception. That said, this is not the appropriate exception to throw in your case. You should throw `IllegalArgumentException`, which is unchecked, and doesn't require a `throws` clause.